# How to make gdb shows modules names in backtrace

Tags: gdb, debug-symbols, backtrace

If all debug symblos are loaded - gdb backtrace shows something like:

```
#0  m4_traceon (obs=0x24eb0, argc=1, argv=0x2b8c8) at builtin.c:993
#1  0x6e38 in expand_macro (sym=0x2b600) at macro.c:242
#2  0x6840 in expand_token (obs=0x0, t=177664, td=0xf7fffb08) at macro.c:71
```

But I need something like:

```
#0  m4_traceon (obs=0x24eb0, argc=1, argv=0x2b8c8) at builtin.c:993 from Lib1.so
#1  0x6e38 in expand_macro (sym=0x2b600) at macro.c:242 from Lib2.so
#2  0x6840 in expand_token (obs=0x0, t=177664, td=0xf7fffb08) at macro.c:71 from MyApp
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to do this.  I think there is a bug in gdb bugzilla that you can track if you are interested.

However, if you really need this, you can rewrite `bt` in Python, and customize it to do whatever you like.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9829 might be what you are referring to. The bug even points to a patch to do in gdb-code, but things might have changed since 2009 when bug was written :)